# Selecting from a matrix according to elements of a column -- efficiency and speed?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning

I need to select all elements from matrix M that have in their 3rd column elements from some given list L (3rd column and L are real numbers). I have written the most obvious (to me) command to select this subset:

```
S = Select[M, MemberQ[L, #[[3]]] &];
```

The problem is that my matrix has 15 millions rows (and 30 columns), L has 500 000 elements and this operation takes ages (on my PC with 32 GB Ram it is running already for more than 24h).

Before I started, my only thought on how to improve the speed was to sort both M and L in increasing order (I mean sort M according to the increasing order of elements of its 3rd column). However it does not seem to help.

I will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Dense matrix or sparse matrix? What kind of data?

Comment: Hi, it is a dense matrix. The relevant column and the list contain only integers. Other columns contain all types -- bytes, longs, doubles, strings etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job for pure integer matrices (hence for packed arrays) in less than 10 seconds on my machine.

```
n = 500000;
L = RandomInteger[{1, 2 n}, n];
M = RandomInteger[{1, 2 n}, {30 n, 30}];
nf = Nearest[L -> Automatic]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
column = Developer`ToPackedArray[M[[All, 3]]];
rowidx = Random`Private`PositionsOf[
     Developer`ToPackedArray[Length /@ nf[column, {1, 0}]],
     1
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
subM = M[[rowidx]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.065254
>
> 8.17927
>
> 0.925655

The same strategy applies for purely real matrices. If `M` is of mixed type, the final read operation may take significantly longer, but looking up the row indices should take essentially the same time.

The key ingredient is to use `Nearest`. This will internally create a binary(?) search tree that speeds up the search tremendously. With `nf[column, {1, 0}]`, I specify that I want to fine at most `1` entry in `L` and only if I have a perfect match (distance `0`).

Comment: `Nearest[ ]` is definitely a powerful search tool.

Comment: Fantastic -- it sorted out even a bigger file of 25 millions rows in less than 15 seconds. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome!